# Javascript: using a math function to control an output range according to an input range

Tags: javascript, math, range, algebra

If I know that a ratio of two input variables "a/b" has a range of [1;2]
And if I want my output value of "y" to have a range of [ymin;ymax] of my choice, based on the range of "a/b":

Is there a formula that can bind those two ranges so that I can always find the value of y, whatever the value of "a/b" (knowing it will always be between 1 and 2)?

Practically:

I have a grid that I can zoom.
The number of zoom steps can't be predicted but I know that the ending scale divided by the starting scale will always be between 1 and 2.
And according to that predictable range, I would like to proportionally output an opacity value to my gridlines going from a min value to a max value of my choice.

So let say, I would like my opacity values to range from 0.12 to 0.38 (it's just an example) according to the zoom level:

The formula will make sure that if the scale ratio is 1 then the opacity will be 0.12 and if the scale ratio is 2, then the opacity will be 0.38. And all opacity values In between would remain "proportional" (an increase of scale of 50% = an increase of opacity of 50%, etc..).
And that should work for any output range of my choice.

So I wonder if looking for a formula to achieve this is reasonable or if it's harder to compute than it seems.

Something like this

```
let opacity[from desired min to max] = (endScale/startScale)[from 1 to 2] * something + opacityMin;
```

But that's linear and would probably not fit my needs...

I tried to plot some points on paper in order to figure that out.
Here is what I ploted with the 0.12 to 0.38 example, considering the same progression within the input range and the output range:

```
Input      Output   percentage   multiplier
--------------------------------------------

1          0.12     0%           (* 0.12)
1.25       0.185    25%          (* 0.148)
1.5        0.25     50%          (* 0.166..)
1.75       0.315    75%          (* 0.18)
2          0.38     100%         (* 0.19)
```

If I predict the output I need using some input values between 1 and 2, the coefficients are not matching of course. So I don't know how to bind those two ranges.

Any hep would be appreciated. At least to get some guidance.

Comment: Does my recent answer about linear formula helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927568/3807365

Comment: Thank you. But according to my plots, the curves I find don't follow a linear curve. That's the problem and that's what makes this thing hard for me to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an existing good algorithm for that, but from your description of the problem I can recommend doing something like that:

```js
const zoomMin = 1;
const zoomMax = 2;
const opacityMin = 0.12;
const opacityMax = 0.38;

function getOpacityLevel(zoomLevel) {
  const zoomRange = (zoomMax - zoomMin);
  const opacityRange = (opacityMax - opacityMin);
  
  const zoomLevelPercent = (zoomLevel - zoomMin) / zoomRange;
  const opacityLevel = (opacityRange * zoomLevelPercent) + opacityMin;
  
  return opacityLevel;
}


console.log(getOpacityLevel(1.0));
console.log(getOpacityLevel(1.25));
console.log(getOpacityLevel(1.5));
console.log(getOpacityLevel(1.75));
console.log(getOpacityLevel(2.0));
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need, thanks. I'm testing it as we speak.
I thought there would be a built-in function for something like this. If it does what it seems to do, I'll validate your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: It works like a charm and thanks to you, I now have an infinitely zoomable grid with a seamless change in gridlines opacity. I worked on it all day and you provided the finish touch I was missing for hours. Thanks and take care !

Answer (score 1):

```
const range = (props) => {
      const { rangeInput, rangeOutPut, input } = props
      if(rangeInput.length && rangeOutPut.length && input){
         const BindingMinInput = rangeInput[0]
         const BindingMaxInput = rangeInput[1]
         const BindingMin = rangeOutPut[0]
         const BindingMax = rangeOutPut[1]
         const outPutMax = (function(){
              if(BindingMinInput === input ){
                return BindingMin
              }
              if(BindingMaxInput === input ){
                return BindingMax
              }
              const test = BindingMaxInput - input 
              return BindingMax * test
            }())
         
            return outPutMax
       } else {
         throw new Error('Props is undefined, or badly formatted')
      }
    }
    range({ 
            rangeInput:[ 1, 2 ], 
            rangeOutPut:[ 10, 100 ], 
            input:1
         })
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is a script here below that seem to do what I need in a very straight forward way. Your script might work just as well but it's too involved compared to my knowledge of javascript. Just by curiosity, did you check the code below and does it output the same values? If so, I will try to understand your script in order to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: I changed it a bit for readability, but yes it works

Comment: I gave it a try, it seems that if I put it up to 1.99 it returns just fine, but 2, it doubles the input value, as I didn't use ts either to help, it's going to be bad to debug now lol

Comment: Ok, so I don't fell too bad using Telman's script then ;-)
Thank you and take care.

Comment: apparently I missed the scope, it happens in functional js, when you are not 100%

Comment: this function works similar to a react hook, now that I fixed it, you can just call range props, in this case in each file you would define new range values, without having to write it again in another file, with different constants

Comment: now it is as it should, but it shows the exact value of js, you could put a toFixed if you want to get rid of some decimals

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it randomly.

```
 var float = Math.random().toFixed(2)
 console.log(1 + parseFloat(float))
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't need it to be random at all. I want it to be kind of proportional (even though it's not linear).
For instance, if I decide my output range to go from 0.12 to 0.38 for an input going from 1 to 2,then  I expect a=1 to output 0.12, a=2 to output 0.38 and a=1.5 to output 0.25. Those values are easy enough but any intermediate value should be computed by a formula. But I can't find it. Of course, this formula should work for any output range I decide...

Comment: I'll give an attractive if I can do it, I found it interesting.