# How to Use Negative Values in Lerp Function as Alpha Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-three-fiber, lerp

**I am trying to animate some text on the screen in two ways:**

1. Move its Y position from 1 to -1 **[already finished]**
2. Shift its RGB color value from white(255,255,255) to
   green(149,184,6) **[need help with]**

I am using the Linear Interpolation function from [npm lerp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerp) to calculate a value between each RGB color channel.

```
const r = Math.floor(lerp(255, 149, alpha));
const g = Math.floor(lerp(255, 184, alpha));
const b = Math.floor(lerp(255, 6, alpha));
```

The lerp function `alpha` parameter requires a percentage decimal value from 0 to 1, but I would like to use the texts position from -1 to 1 as the dynamic alpha value while the texts position changes.

To visualize this animation, please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxqUIZ6kBTI&t=5869s)

**Using react-three-fiber, I am changing the text's color value using this line:**

```
ref.current.color = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
```

I need help writing a function that takes in an input value between 1 and -1, and then converts it to an output value between 0 and 1 for the alpha parameter in the lerp function.

```js
function translate(positionY){
  //translates
}
const positionY = -0.5;
console.log(translate(positionY)) //.75
```

[image]

**This function will be used to get the alpha for the lerp function:**

```
const r = Math.floor(lerp(255, 149, translate(positionY)));
const g = Math.floor(lerp(255, 184, translate(positionY)));
const b = Math.floor(lerp(255, 6, translate(positionY)));
```

Comment: you want to convert from [-1,1] to [0,1] ? why not `(y+1)/2` ?

Comment: @ITgoldman Thank you but (-.5+1)/2 = .25    It should be .75

Comment: so do a 1 minus that: `1-(y+1)/2`

Comment: @ITgoldman Perfect, would you mind writing a solution explaining how you did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this linear stuff basically means that between 2 points there's only one line. So if you got 2 points right, then you got the right formula for all other points on the line.

So I started with [-1, 1] to [0, 1] transformation. It's clear to see that there should be `/2` there because the range is double. But before we do I 'translate' it so that -1 will be equal 0 (and when I `/2` it will stay 0).

Then I needed to reverse the 0 with 1 for the output, so I did a minus 1 for the result. Frankly I tried apply same logic but was too lazy.

Then I remembered I had an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927568/3807365) about that. It's a function that gets (x1,y1, x2, y2) and returns a linear function.

```js
var x1 = -1;
var x2 = 1;

var y1 = 1;
var y2 = 0;

var calcY = getLinearFunction(x1, y1, x2, y2);
console.log(calcY(-1))
console.log(calcY(1))

function getLinearFunction(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
  return function(x) {
    return slope * (x - x1) + y1;
  }
}
```